# avoid "Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction" error between SQL 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, msdtc

in our production environment we have a stored procedure (in sql 2005 server) that import data into a local table from a remote stored procedure (stored in a remote sql 2008).

The code is like this:

```
insert  <<local table name>> (fund, strat, clr, [id], position, unsettledPosition)
exec    <<remote stored proc name>> 'aapl us' , '2013-05-13'
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction.

and

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

I have configured both local and remote DTC allowing DTC Access over Network, Allowing Remote Clients option, also allowing Inbound & Outbound Communication, and finally enabling XA Transactions, but without any success.

Until yesterday the remote server was an old SQL 2005 and my code worked well, then I guess I miss some config settings in the new server 2008.

Please could someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is easily reproduced, with MSDTC turned on:

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION;

...

SAVE TRANSACTION abc;
```

According to [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295027), the ability to use SAVEPOINTs in a Distributed transaction was dropped in SQL 7, 
i.e. not a breaking change in SQL 2008 (R2).

It is likely that you previously were NOT running under a Distributed Transaction, but now are, e.g. previously, the remote proc may have been on a different database on the same server, hence no need for a DTC transaction.

So unfortunately, it seems you need to either drop the bounding ACID transaction, or change the SPROC on the remote server so it doesn't use SAVEPOINTs.

**Update**
As per the comments below, it appears that the [REMOTE_PROC_TRANSACTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189322%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option had been set on the OP's newer SQL 2008 server, which automatically begins a distributed transaction across remote stored proc calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but also before we had this error, finally resolved changing some settings. But the old remote server is now shutted down and I cannot read the configs...

Comment: It might be [SET REMOTE_PROC_TRANSACTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189322(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Maybe you are right! Let me try also tomorrow.. for now, my proc seems to works fine.